# how to set multiple buttons in UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to set multiple buttons in UIScrollView and also how to set clicked action for particular button index?

Comment: Have you already tried something? Is there some specific problem you can trouble with?..

Comment: Sounds to me like what you really need is UITableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call this(initScrollView) method on viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 

arrayScrollViewImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
     [[MyKeyValuePair alloc] initWithKey:@"imagename1" withValue:@"imagename1.png"],
     [[MyKeyValuePair alloc] initWithKey:@"imagename2" withValue:@"imagename2.png"],nil];


[self initScrollView];

}
```

**here arrayScrollViewImages is NSArray**

```
- (void) initScrollView
 {

    int width = 10;
    for (int index = 0; index < [arrayScrollViewImages count]; index++) {
        MyKeyValuePair *pair = [arrayScrollViewImages objectAtIndex:index];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:pair.value];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(width, 2, 34, 34)];
        [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTag:index];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        if (index == 0) {
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.59 green:0.38 blue:0.21 alpha:1.00]];
        }

        [scrollView addSubview:button];
        width += 45;
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 48);
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
}


- (void) scrollViewButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    for (UIButton *b in scrollView.subviews) {
        if ([b isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            [b setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        }
    }

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.59 green:0.38 blue:0.21 alpha:1.00]];
    MyKeyValuePair *pair = [arrayScrollViewImages objectAtIndex:button.tag];
    labelEspecialidad.text = pair.key;
}
```

**here MyKeyValuePair is a one class**
**MyKeyValuePair.h**

```
@interface MyKeyValuePair : NSObject {
    NSString *key;
    NSString *value;
}

// Properties
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *key;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *value;

@end
```

**MyKeyValuePair.m**

```
@implementation MyKeyValuePair
@synthesize key, value;

- (id) initWithKey: (NSString *) _key withValue: (NSString *) _value {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.key = _key;
        self.value = _value;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [self.key release];
    [self.value release];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIScrollView *view = ..;
UIButton *button1 = ... ;
button1.tag = 1;
UIButton *button2 = ... ;
button1.tag = 2;
UIButton *button3 = ... ;
button1.tag = 3;
[view addSubview:button1];
[view addSubview:button2];
[view addSubview:button3];
```

In IBAction method check button tag to identify clicked button.

Comment: nice suggestion, but i think he is not able to build UI via placing elements programmatically if he asks for such beginners problem

Answer (score 0):

Using XCode Interface Builder

- Add buttons (select and drag&drop them from side objects panel)
- Create `IBAction` for every button (in owner class `.h` and implement in `.m`)
- Link buttons to actions via right mouse click&drag

See some video tutorials on youtube, such as

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgAAvRQBrPc
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAdmetwz7sc
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vixD-N6cbDY

and read Developer Guide

- http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-your-first-iphone-application-with-interface-builder
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of buttons for that purpose. Assign a unique tag id to each button, and programmatically spread the buttons along the UIScrollView. Have the UIScrollView listen to the Touch Up Inside event, where you can then determine which button has been clicked by the unique tag ID.